# How to get an Element from a vector without using numbers or indices?

Tags: r

Lets say I have these two vectors in my R workspace with the following content:

```
[1] "Atom.Type" and "Molar.Mass"

> Atom.Type 
[1] "Oxygen" "Lithium" "Nitrogen" "Hydrogen"
> Molar.Mass
[1] 16 6.9 14 1
```

I now want to assign the *Molar.Mass* belonging to *"Lithium"* (i.e. 6.9) to a new variable called *mass*.

The problem is: I have to do that **without** using any numbers or indices.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this problem?

Comment: You haven't defined an explicit relationship between these two vectors, but if you are willing to rely on their respective orders, then `Molar.Mass[which(Atom.Type == "Lithium")]` would work, as @MorganBall answered. However, it would be safer to establish a more explicit correspondence between the elements of the two vectors. For example, if you set the names attribute of `Molar.Mass` to be `Atom.Type` (`names(Molar.Mass) <- Atom.Type`), you can treat this as a dictionary / map-like structure: `Molar.Mass["Lithium"]`.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, both ways work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `mass<-Molar.Mass[Atom.Type=="Lithium"]` Clearly this assumes the two vectors are of the same length and sorted correctly. See additional comment from Roland below.

Comment: You don't need `which` since R also offers subsetting using logical vectors.